# How to calculate combined power of two amplifiers

Tags: amplifier, theory

If I have 1 amplifier running at 95%, and another identical one running at 60%, how may I calculate the output power of the combiner? I believe this combiner is a "Magic T", but if there is a different formula for each type of combiner, please enlighten me.

I understand that them both running at 95% would produce an output of 95%, and that running one at 90% and one at 60% does not produce an output of 75%.

I assume, based on this document, this process involves combining phasors: https://www.ramayes.com/Data%20Files/Communications%20Power%20Industries/500-Watt%20Pwr-Phase%20Combiner.pdf

Comment: Sorry, this isn't clear at all. What does "running at x %" even mean? x% of what? Combining what? What combiners, specifically? Your question cites three different percentages, to increase the confusion... could you maybe draw a rough schematic about what you want to do?

Comment: Welcome to hamSE. Please, add a picture or point us to a description of the combiner you're using and indicate the frequency of operation.

Comment: I am speaking in abstract terms with two UHF 100W amplifiers being combined by a Magic T combiner. The percentages are of their maximum PEP.